# How to count comparisons in quicksort algorithm

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I've got an algorithm for quick-sorting and I'm trying to count the number of comparisons in it. It uses a randomly generated array of sizes 10, 100, 1000, and 10,000, and has a constant seed, so it generates the same values in the array each time. (So the results can be pre-determined and compared to check if the counting is correct). The values I'm getting are 13, 147, 1506, and 11014. What I am expecting is 25, 630, 10292, and 132882.

```
/**
 * @file quicksort.hpp
 */

#ifndef QUICKSORT_H
#define QUICKSORT_H

#include <algorithm>

static const int MIN_SIZE  = 10; // Smallest size of an array that quicksort will sort

/**
 * Sorts the items in an array into ascending order.
 * @pre  None.
 * @post  theArray is sorted into ascending order; n is unchanged.
 * @param theArray  The given array.
 * @param first  The first element to consider in theArray.
 * @param last  The last element to consider in theArray.
 * @return the number of comparisons
 */
template<class ItemType>
int insertionSort(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int unsorted = first + 1; unsorted <= last; unsorted++) {
        ItemType nextItem = theArray[unsorted];
        int loc = unsorted;
        while ((loc > first) && (counter++, theArray[loc - 1] > nextItem)) {
            
            theArray[loc] = theArray[loc - 1];
            loc--;
        }
        theArray[loc] = nextItem;
    }
    return counter;
}

/**
 * Arranges two specified array entries into sorted order by
 * exchanging them, if necessary.
 * @param theArray  The given array.
 * @param i  The index of the first entry to consider in theArray.
 * @param j  The index of the second entry to consider in theArray.
 * */
template<class ItemType>
void order(ItemType theArray[], int i, int j) {
    if (theArray[i] > theArray[j]) {
        std::swap(theArray[i], theArray[j]);
    }
}

/** 
 * Arranges the first, middle, and last entry in an array in sorted order.
 * @pre  theArray[first..last] is an array; first <= last.
 * @post  theArray[first..last] is is arranged so that its
 * first, middle, and last entries are in sorted order.
 * @param theArray  The given array.
 * @param first  The first entry to consider in theArray.
 * @param last  The last entry to consider in theArray.
 * @return  The index of the middle entry.
 */
template<class ItemType>
int sortFirstMiddleLast(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last) {
    int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
    order(theArray, first, mid); // Make theArray[first] <= theArray[mid]
    order(theArray, mid, last);  // Make theArray[mid] <= theArray[last]
    order(theArray, first, mid); // Make theArray[first] <= theArray[mid]

    return mid;
}

/**
 * Partitions the entries in an array about a pivot entry for quicksort.
 * @pre  theArray[first..last] is an array; first <= last.
 * @post  theArray[first..last] is partitioned such that:
 * S1 = theArray[first..pivotIndex-1] <= pivot * theArray[pivotIndex] == pivot
 * S2 = theArray[pivotIndex+1..last]  >= pivot
 * @param theArray  The given array.
 * @param first  The first entry to consider in theArray.
 * @param last  The last entry to consider in theArray.
 * @return  The index of the pivot.
 */
template<class ItemType>
int partition(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last, int counter) {
    // Choose pivot using median-of-three selection
    int pivotIndex = sortFirstMiddleLast(theArray, first, last);

    // Reposition pivot so it is last in the array
    std::swap(theArray[pivotIndex], theArray[last - 1]);
    pivotIndex = last - 1;
    ItemType pivot = theArray[pivotIndex];

    // Determine the regions S1 and S2
    int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
    int indexFromRight = last - 2;

    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        // Locate first entry on left that is >= pivot
        
        while (counter++, theArray[indexFromLeft] < pivot) {
            
            indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;
        }
        
        // Locate first entry on right that is <= pivot
        while (counter++, theArray[indexFromRight] > pivot) {
            indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;
            
        }
    
        if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {
            std::swap(theArray[indexFromLeft], theArray[indexFromRight]);
            indexFromLeft = indexFromLeft + 1;
            indexFromRight = indexFromRight - 1;
            
        }
        else {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    // Place pivot in proper position between S1 and S2, and mark its new location
    std::swap(theArray[pivotIndex], theArray[indexFromLeft]);
    pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;

    counter++;

    return pivotIndex;
}

/**
 * Sorts an array into ascending order. Uses the quick sort with
 * median-of-three pivot selection for arrays of at least MIN_SIZE
 * entries, and uses the insertion sort for other arrays.
 * @pre  theArray[first..last] is an array.
 * @post  theArray[first..last] is sorted.
 * @param theArray  The given array.
 * @param first  The first element to consider in theArray.
 * @param last  The last element to consider in theArray.
 * @return the number of comparisons
 */
template<class ItemType>
int quicksort(ItemType theArray[], int first, int last, int& counter) {
    
    if (last - first + 1 < MIN_SIZE) {
        counter += insertionSort(theArray, first, last);
    }
    else {
        // Create the partition: S1 | Pivot | S2
        int pivotIndex = partition(theArray, first, last, counter);

        // Sort subarrays S1 and S2
        quicksort(theArray, first, pivotIndex - 1, counter);
        quicksort(theArray, pivotIndex + 1, last, counter);
    }
    return counter; 
}

#endif
```

This is the code for the quicksort.

```
std::cout << "Quicksort                               ";
    std::cout << "    " << std::left << quicksort(makeRandomArray(10, seed), 0, 10-1, comparisons);
    comparisons = 0;
    std::cout << "    " << quicksort(makeRandomArray(100, seed), 0, 100-1, comparisons);
    comparisons = 0;
    std::cout << "    " << quicksort(makeRandomArray(1000, seed), 0, 1000-1, comparisons);
    comparisons = 0;
    std::cout << "    " << quicksort(makeRandomArray(10000, seed), 0, 10000-1, comparisons) << std::endl;
```

And this is the code in the main.cpp file for printing out the quick-sort comparisons. I am aware it's not pretty or efficient but for now, it works. I just want to get my quick-sort counting accurate.
Edit: Code for the array generator:

```
int* makeRandomArray(int n, int seed) {
srand(seed);
int * a = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = rand() % 1000;
}
return a;
```

}

Comment: Why do you expect these particular, very specific, numbers of comparisons? Where did 25, 630, 10292, and 132882 come from?

Comment: There's a comparison inside `order` that you don't count.

Comment: These numbers come from the seed. When you put it in arrays of 10, 100, 1000, 10,000, the random number generator is generating the same numbers every time. I'll edit the post to include the code for the array generator. (The seed is preset to 9000)

Comment: @imnapr They asked where the "What I am expecting" numbers are coming from, not how you're generating the array contents.

Comment: But how is the number `25` arrived at? Why do you expect the algorithm to make, for your particular seed and the particular array generated from it, exactly 25 comparisons, no more and no less? For that matter, why do you even care about the exact number of comparisons?

Comment: The what Im expecting numbers come from just manually counting it. The array can be printed out and I can manually do the quicksort myself and then just count the number of comparisons to be made and then compare it to the program.

Comment: _Side note:_ You are not using `std:vector` because...?

Comment: @imnapr Well, I used the quicksort code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c), and generated [this program](https://godbolt.org/z/q73affEYx) to get the comparison count.  This basically uses the answer given by JerryCoffin.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd probably create a small class template that overloaded `operator<` to count how often it was called.

```cpp
template <class T>
class comparison_counter {
    static unsigned comparisons = 0;
    T value;
public:
    comparison_counter(T t) : value(t) {}
    bool operator<(comparison_counter const &other) { 
        ++comparisons;
        return value < other.value;
    }

    comparison_counter &operator=(T t) { value = t; return *this; }

    void reset_counter() { comparisons = 0; }
    // ...
};

unsigned comparison_counter::comparisons;
```

I didn't examine your code in detail--you may need to support a few more operations that give access to the underlying value, but that would be the general idea.

With this, instead of sorting a `std::vector<int>` you'd sort a `std::vector<comparison_counter<int>>`. When you're done sorting, `comparison_counter::comparisons` will hold a count of how many comparisons were done.

A couple caveats:

- If you do more than one sort, you need to call `reset_counter` in between.
- This isn't currently thread-safe (though I doubt you care).

Comment: +1 Nice answer. This is how I would do it, too. In the OP's use case, array size tops out at 10,000. In general, however, the number of comparisons is (roughly) related to the size of the array. You could, therefore, use `std::size_t` or `std::vector<T>::size_type` as the type for variable `comparisons`, rather than `unsigned`.